# "OceanWP Setting" is missing in "Edit page" interface

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpbakery

I am new in word press. I installed WPBakery Page 6.2.0 plugin in WordPress.I have installed the OceanWP theme.

The tutorial I am following has "OceanWP Setting" on the edit page. Here is a link to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp7TaaJZKeU)

**Tutorial on Edit Page:**

[image]

I 'Edit' my'page' I got this display

**My Installed WPBakery Page Builder on Edit Page:**

[image]
In this interface, the "OceanWP Setting" is missing.

How I can get "OceanWP Setting" on the edit page?

Comment: Did you check with the original authors of the theme regarding this matter ?

Comment: @amilaishere I downloaded the theme from this link (https://wordpress.org/themes/oceanwp/) and uploaded it in Word press. I think "OceanWP Setting" is not because of the OceanWP theme but because of the WPBakery plugin. I don't know the setting WPBakery plugin setting that introduces the  "OceanWP Setting" in the edit page interface.

Comment: If you go to the theme doc you will find this - https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/827-introduction-to-oceanwp-settings

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to install a Plugin name **"Essential Addons for Elementor"** from Plugins => Add New

That will just solve the problem

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this plugin. "OceanWP Extra". It is from OceanWP developers.